# Adding a row from a dataframe into another by matching columns with NaN values in row pandas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, nan

### The Scenario:

I have 2 dataframes `fc0` and `yc0`. Where `fc0` is a Cluster and `yc0` is another dataframe which needs to be merged in `fc0`.

The Nature of data is as follows:

**fc0**

```
uid         1         2         3         4         5         6  
234  235  4.000000  4.074464  4.128026  3.973045  3.921663  4.024864   
235  236  3.524208  3.125669  3.652112  3.626923  3.524318  3.650589   
236  237  4.174080  4.226267  4.200133  4.150983  4.124157  4.200052
```

**yc0**

```
iid  uid    1    2    5    6    9    15
0    944  5.0  3.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  5.0
```

### The Twist

I have 1682 columns in **fc0** and I have few hundered values in **yc0**. Now I need the **yc0** to go into **fc0**

In haste of resolving it, I even tried `yc0.reset_index(inplace=True)` but wasn't really helpful.

### Expected Output

```
     uid         1         2         3         4         5         6  
234  235  4.000000  4.074464  4.128026  3.973045  3.921663  4.024864   
235  236  3.524208  3.125669  3.652112  3.626923  3.524318  3.650589   
236  237  4.174080  4.226267  4.200133  4.150983  4.124157  4.200052
944  5.0       3.0       NaN       NaN       4.0       3.0       3.0
```

### References

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe) Tried this, but landed up inserting NaN values for 1st 16 Columns and rest of the data shifted by that many columns

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas) Couldn't match column keys, besides I tried it for row.

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333157/combining-2-dataframes) Merging doesn't match the columns in it.

[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972410/pandas-combine-two-columns-in-a-dataframe#10972557) Concatenation doesn't work that way.

[Link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773683/combine-two-pandas-dataframes-with-the-same-index) Same issues with Join.

### EDIT 1

```
fc0.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 235 entries, 234 to 468
Columns: 1683 entries, uid to 1682
dtypes: float64(1682), int64(1)
memory usage: 3.0 MB
```

and

```
yc0.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Columns: 336 entries, uid to 1007
dtypes: float64(335), int64(1)
memory usage: 2.7 KB
```

Comment: Is it right that the values in your yc0 DataFrame don't align with the columns in your expected output? For example in yc0 the uid value is 944, but in the expected output 944 is the index, and uid is now 5.0.

Comment: @Ben well, when I see that in show variables of Pycharm, I can see the uid is 944 but when I print it, it shows iid   uid in yc0. So I'm quite confused which one is correct!

Comment: Can you show the info for both input data frames in your question.  fc0.info() and yc0.info() ?

Comment: @ScottBoston Please check in Edit 1 of Question.

Comment: It seems that you need to adjust the columns in your yc0 dataframe.  You could try something like isolate the columns that are numerical, df.columns = df.columns - 1 then use pd.concat.  Pandas will align the columns based on the column index.  The trick for you is get the columns of your yc0 datafame to line up correctly with your fc0 dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston I just tried this, but again same thing happend. The Values did concat but it did not go with column ids. anymore solution?

Comment: @ScottBoston I tried a simple example from [docs] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) . Since that is in dictionary to datafrMe, I'm unable to resolve my problem. Any insights you could share will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a MVCE example.    Does this small sample data show the functionality that you are expecting?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,4)), columns=list('ABCE'))

    A   B   C   E
0  81  57  54  88
1  63  63  74  10
2  13  89  88  66
3  90  81   3  31
4  66  93  55   4

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,4)), columns=list('BCDE'))

    B   C   D   E
0  93  48  62  25
1  24  97  52  88
2  53  50  21  13
3  81  27   7  81
4  10  21  77  19

df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
      A   B   C     D   E
0  81.0  57  54   NaN  88
1  63.0  63  74   NaN  10
2  13.0  89  88   NaN  66
3  90.0  81   3   NaN  31
4  66.0  93  55   NaN   4
0   NaN  93  48  62.0  25
1   NaN  24  97  52.0  88
2   NaN  53  50  21.0  13
3   NaN  81  27   7.0  81
4   NaN  10  21  77.0  19
```